# Website not styling correctly in IE9 per dns alias (website.co.com)?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, dns

I have an mvc3 website that is not styling correctly in IE9 when I hit it through an alias that I setup internal to my company portal, http://webapp.co.com.  If I hit the IP directly http://xx.xx.xxx.xx it styles correctly in IE9.  Firefox and Chrome style correctly either way.

What's going on here?

Comment: IE9 switches to Compatibility View depending on the security settings and the environment.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to prevent the request or site coming as being translated as an intranet site (disallow compatibility view)?

Comment: Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` to your page head.

Comment: You should put `IE=edge` so that when IE10 is released, your page isn't stuck in IE9 mode.

Comment: @BoltClock: BoltClock...you rock...thanks!  :)

Comment: @thirtydot: Good point. I've posted an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE switches to Compatibility View depending on the security settings and the environment. In your case, accessing your web app through your intranet address causes IE to fall back to that mode.

Simply add the following meta tag to your page head and IE9 will stop rendering your page in Compatibility View:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```